# when looping through a slice of a list in python, I am not able to index correctly

Tags: python, list, loops, indexing, slice

When looping through a slice of a list in python, I am not able to index correctly:

I first created a list containing integers from 1 to 10, and my goal is to multiply the first 5 elements by 10 by looping over the first 5 elements in the list. However, it is the 2nd to the 6th elements that ended up being multiplied.

Expected result: `[10,20,30,40,50 6,7,8,9,10]`

Actual result: `[1,20,30,40,50 60,7,8,9,10]`

I tried indexing in different ways such as `[:5]`; `[0:5]`. I do not know what else I can do now.

Here is the code I have:

```
lst = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
for j in lst[0:3]:
    lst[j] = lst[j] * 10
print(lst)
```

Comment: Hint: don't `change/operate` the list items `while you're looping` them... It's one of the common/well-know problem.

Comment: There're some answers under your question, so you can [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) one which you find most helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Your list slice:

```
lst[0:3]
```

expands to the first three elements of the list (1, 2, 3).

Even if you did:

```
lst[0:5]
```

instead, to get the first 5 elements (1, 2, 3, 4, 5), that still wouldn't work in this case.

The reason is because `j` would take on those values, in each iteration of the loop. But, list indexes start at 0. You could offset the indexes (`j - 1`), but that still wouldn't solve your problem.

You don't want to be iterating over the values of the list -- they can be arbitrary numbers. You can't rely on them to iterate through. Instead, use the [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) function. It will generate a sequence of numbers with which to iterate over.

In your case, `range(5)` would do the trick. It will generate 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 -- which will allow you to correctly index the list.

Here is a working example:

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
for j in range(5):
    lst[j] = lst[j] * 10
print(lst)
```

Which gives the desired output:

```
[10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Answer (score 1):

earlier post has offered great solution. Alternatively, this is one way to mimic your original approach: [first elem. is -10, 2nd: -9.... and last item is -1. Counting from backward]

```
N = len(lst)   # 10

for i in range(-N, -5, 1):
    lst[i] *=  10
    
print(lst)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set value of generator which multiplies first **N** elements to first **N** elements in one line:

```py
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
N = 6
lst[0:N] = (i * 10 for i in lst[0:N])
```